# Add Items to SharePoint List with SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, core-api

I want to add some Items into my `SharePoint 2010 List` with `SharePoint API` in C# but I don't know what is the URL for do this and how to use that URL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In JavaScript or C#?

Comment: I want to do this in C#

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use REST, you can simply use the C# client-side API that wraps HTTP calls.
You can find all basic operations performed with client-side C# API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks.

**Create a new list item with C# client API**

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Body"] = "Hello World!"; 
newItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**[EDIT]**

Most of the time, there's not point in calling the REST API from C#, since the SP client DLLs already do the hard work of creating/sending/decoding HTTP requests to the server. The REST API is more usefull for non-Microsoft languages (e.g. PHP, Java) or maybe in JavaScript. That's why you'll find very few samples of C# code that call to the REST API. The best approach would then to translate JavaScript code like found at (http://chuvash.eu/2011/12/15/update-list-items-with-listdata-svc/) to C#. Here's the JavaScript code, copied from the mentionned article:

**Create a new list item with the REST API (SP2010), called from JavaScript**

```
//create
var url = "/teamsite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyContacts";
var contact = {
    FirstName: "Arnie",
    Title: "Dell",
    WorkCity: "Lund"
};
var body = JSON.stringify(contact);
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     processData: false,
     data: body,
     success: function () {
       alert('Contact Saved.');
     }
});
```

Comment: thank u but i want to make API for my customers maybe they can't use c#

Comment: You wrote you wanted C# code... + what do you mean by "make API"?

Comment: I have one customer and he ask me to give API to him for add into my sharepoint list now i don't know what  should i do this is problem

Comment: Create a C# DLL, that will wrap the base client-side API thanks to the code above. Give this new DLL to your Customer, along with the base client-side API DLLs, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll.

Comment: I want to use URL APIs like this http://developer3/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Courses')/items for add new items in list

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: + note: the URL you give as an example "developer3/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Courses')/items" is available only on SP2013. In SP2010, the REST API was less developped, and used a URL in the form "/developer3/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Courses"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct permissions you can even do it with C# HTTP classes, a SharePoint Context or even simple JavaScript and Ajax methods using the REST API or ListData.svc.

And oData POST is typically for a CREATE operation.

[Using the REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)